# Magento 2: multiwebsite issue on cloudways

Tags: magento2, multi-website

I am trying to add a new website on my current Magento 2 store. I have followed the steps in this tutorial: https://help.nexcess.net/magento-2/how-to-configure-magento-2-storefronts but still I am not able to access the storefront, when I access the website it shows this error:
[image]

I am not sure what is missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you first confirm that, you are setting the URL properly into the admin and also created symbolic links directory for that URL.

Comment: Yes I have added the URL properly in the admin and also created the symbolic links. I hve added a random domain name just by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change settings from the admin section:

Go to admin->store->configuration->General->Web

and in Url Options setting enable Add Store Code to Urls to Yes

Now Clean all cache.